# is there a better way to set global variables in a script

Tags: python, coding-style

I've written a function in another file, basically `doLostOfStuff`
and to call, it, I have my main.py file pass variables to it.  Something like this

```
def doLotsOfStuff(v1,v2,v3):
    return v1+v2+v3

def initializeVariables():
    v1= 1
    v2 = 2
    v3 = 3
    return(v1,v2,v3)

myV1,myV2,myV3 = initializeVariables()
doLotsOfStuff(myV1,myV2,myV3 )
```

The thing is, in my actual code there are a lot of variables, with long names and the initializing line is about 90 columns wide.

Is there a better/cleaner way to call doLotsOfStuff`?  I just feel like this makes for code that isn't easy to read.

Comment: Sorry but if you want readable code a function shouldn't do lots of stuff. Some even argue that a function should do one precise thing. But yes unpacking can help you see the answer.

Comment: You probably can also also consolidate some of the vars in object attributes and pass single objects grouping them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
args = initializeVariables()
doLotsOfStuff(*args)
```